# Python creates 2 times more threads than expected

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm new to Python so my apologies if this is something obvious.

I'm trying to build multi threaded application, however when I want to create a thread I get two instead of one.

**MyThread.py**

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class MyThreadClass(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print "starting " + self.getName() + "\n"
        from main import var1
        while True:
            print self.getName() + " is running\n"
            print "value: " + var1 + "\n"
            time.sleep(1)
```

**main.py**

```
from MyThread import MyThreadClass
var1 = "Test"
MyThreadClass().start()
```

The output I get

```
 Thread-1 is running
 Thread-2 is running
 Thread-1 is running
 Thread-2 is running
 Thread-1 is running
 Thread-2 is running
 .....
```

Why is it happening? I noticed that if I replace `MyThreadClass().start()` with `MyThreadClass().run()` I get 2 threads but only one of them keeps running

```
 Thread-1 is running
 Thread-2 is running
 Thread-2 is running
 Thread-2 is running
 Thread-2 is running
 .....
```

Any idea what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you import `main.py` in `MyThread.py`, the line

> MyThreadClass().start()

gets executed once again (since the module gets loaded), hence a second thread is started.

---

You could create a guard clause in `main.py` by replacing that line with

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyThreadClass().run()
```

or better, just pass `var1` to `MyThreadClass` as a parameter to avoid the circular dependency.

**MyThread.py**:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

class MyThreadClass(Thread):

    def __init__(self, var1):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.var1 = var1

    def run(self):
        print "starting " + self.getName() + "\n"
        while True:
            print self.getName() + " is running\n"
            print "value: " + self.var1 + "\n"
            time.sleep(1)
```

**main.py**

```
from MyThread import MyThreadClass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyThreadClass("Test").run()
```

Answer (score 4):

You're starting the thread twice, once when you run `main.py` (because it's the `__main__` module then), and once again when you import it in `MyThreadClass`'s `run()` method.

`import` statements will run all code within the module, not just what you ask for; the `from` form is a convenience to bring a specific item into your current namespace.

The reason it stops at two threads is because even though you import `main` again in the second thread, Python will not re-execute the module's code because it's already been loaded.  If it hadn't been for that, you'd have many more than two threads ;-)

Using the `if __name__ == '__main__':` structure mentioned in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158930/722332) is very useful not just for this situation but for all types of modules, because it allows you to both execute them (many modules will use this for test code) and import them while avoiding side effects.